# Did the 4th Prophecy of Trakor come to pass?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *DS9* ["Destiny"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/461.htm), the Third Prophecy of Trakor comes true over the course of the episode.

At the end, Sisko and a Vedic have the following exchange:

> **YARKA:** There are signs that Trakor's fourth prophecy will soon come to pass as well.
>
> **SISKO:** Don't tell me that has something to do with me?
>
> **YARKA:** You, Commander? Well, it is a prophecy about the Emissary.
>
> **SISKO:** Tell me about it.
>
> **YARKA:** The fourth prophecy says that the *Emissary will face a fiery trial and he'll be forced to choose*...

**Did the fourth prophecy come true?  Does Sisko being "forced to choose" correspond to some particular event in any later *DS9* episode?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably refers to the **confrontation between Sisko and Dukat in the Bajoran Fire Caves** in the DS9 episode [*What You Leave Behind*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind_(episode)).

"*the Emissary will face a fiery trial and he'll be forced to choose...*"

> The Emissary is Sisko. He certainly faces a "fiery trial" when he and Dukat plunge into the fire pit, and being "forced to choose" could refer to his choice to propel himself and Dukat over the cliff, sacrificing his own life (in a sense) in order to thwart Dukat.

Comment: Nice work, +1!  That's a sound choice.  This is also the point where I am supposed to put in the obligatory, "Good work for someone who never saw the episodes". ;-)

Comment: Spoiler tags might be in order (maybe...your call).

Comment: @Praxis I'll take your word for it, since I don't really know how spoilery this is considered to be ;-) OK now, or is the fact that they have a confrontation also spoilery?

Comment: Looks good now!  (It's the final episode of the series, the resolution of one of the biggest plotlines, and encodes the fates of two major characters....)

Comment: `in a sense` In a very good sense, Sisko couldn't have known he would survive.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the conflict in the fire-caves fulfils Trakor's 4th Prophesy and full credit to the writers for keeping it in mind for 4 years until the final episode!

However, there may well have been a 5th Prophecy, which we see come to pass in the beautiful book by S.D.Perry, *Unity* (2003, Pocket Books). I don't want to spoil the denouement: but there is a remarkable coming-together, with everything falling into peaceful place. It would have made a wonderful film.

Comment: This is a nice find and a good answer but would be greatly improved by [edit]ing in evidence to back it up? Also I know you don't want to spoil things but expanding on this would be very helpful to future readers. You can always hide spoilers by beginning a paragraph with `>!`

Comment: This message, while an interesting tidbit to add to a discussion, doesn't really seem to answer the question that was asked here.

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. "the conflict in the fire-caves" technically answers the question, even if it's an unsatisfactory repeat of the previous answer.